# MySQL: lower does not exist

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query like this:

```
SELECT lower (A.label) FROM addresses A;
```

and what I get in return is

```
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION db.lower does not exist
```

I am using

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                            |
| version                 | 5.0.92-community              |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Edition (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                        |
| version_compile_os      | unknown-linux-gnu             |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Never had this issue before on any other system but this one... I was under the impression that lower is an internal function and is always there. What can be wrong?

Comment: Does `SELECT lower('foo');` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the space between `lower` and `(`

```
SELECT lower(A.label) FROM addresses A;
```

Comment: Weird... its the same code that works fine on other servers. Thanks, this did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
lower (A.label)
```

should be

```
lower(A.label)
```

MySQL doesn't like spaces between function name and argument: you are implying a column alias 
`(A.label)` for a column lower otherwise

```
 lower `(A.label)` 
 lower AS `(A.label)`
```

Comment: Hi, your answer was just as good but I xdazz was a minute earlier and since gist is the same I grant the acceptance to him. Sorry :).